# Evaluating $\int_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt6}\int_{y=-x}^{y=x}\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you evaluate this integral?
$$
\int_0^{\sqrt6}\int_{-x}^x\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Start with $\int dy$.

Comment: wouldnt that just be y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just integrate first with respect to $y$ and then with respect to $x$:

$$
\int_0^\sqrt{6}\int_{-x}^x dy\,dx=\int_0^\sqrt{6}\left[y\right]_{y=-x}^{y=x}\,dx=\int_0^\sqrt{6} 2x\,dx=x^2{\Large|}_0^\sqrt{6}=6-0=6.$$

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... I asked a friend and she said that it would be easier to convert it to polar coordinates. Is this true? Or is that harder to do?

Comment: This is straightforward, so I see no reason to complicate things by switching coordinate systems.

Comment: this is how it is usually done unless working in spherical or cylindrical coordinates, when you will use polar.

Comment: @JeremyRowler, your friend must have been joking with you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternate answer: draw the region of integration.  It's a triangle.  The integrand is $1$ so the double integral is the area of the triangle.